# How to limit the number of threads launched using ASyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've got a listview with the list of some user's facebook friends, with each row showing the name and the picture of the friend. To get the picture from Facebook I launch a thread using ASyncTask, following [Gilles Debunne's post "Multithreading For Performance"](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html).

When I scroll down the list until the end, the number of threads launched can be huge, which makes everything very slow until all threads finish their task.

How can I limit the number of threads?

Thanks

Julien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, unless you are willing to limit yourself to API Level 11 (Android 3.0) and higher, you cannot limit the number of threads used by `AsyncTask`. IIRC, it will use up to 20 threads maximum.

If you want fewer than that, you will need to create your own thread pool mechanism and use that instead of `AsyncTask`. Or, clone the code from `AsyncTask` into your own project and modify the characteristics of its own thread pool.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll use LazyList, described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to limit the number of threads in the pool used for the tasks.

Comment: That is only available on API Level 11.

Comment: Actually its "Since: API Level 1"